# NumberFormat.NumberGroupSeparator is not working in Views in ASP.NET Core MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, numbers, number-formatting

In Startup.cs I have this code:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    ...

    services.Configure<RequestLocalizationOptions>(options =>
    {
         CultureInfo en_GB = new CultureInfo("en-GB");
         en_GB.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator = ".";
         en_GB.NumberFormat.NumberGroupSeparator = ",";

         CultureInfo[] supportedCultures = new[]
         {
             en_GB
         };

         options.DefaultRequestCulture = new RequestCulture(en_GB, en_GB);

         options.SupportedCultures = supportedCultures;
         options.SupportedUICultures = supportedCultures;
    });

    ...
}
```

And then when I return a decimal value from backend to a view

```
@model decimal

<span>@Model</span>
```

it renders the number (for example 123456789.012) as:

```
123456789.012
```

Whereas instead it should've been:

```
123,456,789.012
```

And I know that some of you will say that I can convert it to string in the view, for example:

```
@model decimal

@{
    var numberFormatter = new CultureInfo("en-GB").NumberFormat;
    numberFormatter.NumberDecimalSeparator = ".";
    numberFormatter.NumberGroupSeparator = ",";
    var myFormattedNumber = Model.ToString("#,###.###", numberFormatter);
}

<span>@Model</span>
```

And yes, this will show:

```
123,456,789.012
```

But I need a solution where I am not forced to convert the numbers manually to string in order to show the right format. Isn't there a possibility to do so automatically? Also, why is only ***NumberDecimalSeparator*** working properly (I can even use any other character instead of "." and it works, for example "~" or ";") but ***NumberGroupSeparator*** doesn't work at all. I also think there are similar issues with the other attributes of **NumberFormat** such as ***NumberDecimalDigits*** or ***NumberGroupSizes*** etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you configure `Localization` in `startup.cs`,
You also need to use `Standard numeric format strings` to format data in the View.

**For Example:**

I configure localization like this:

```
var app = builder.Build();
   
//i am using RequestLocalization middleware to configure localization in .Net 6
var defaultDateCulture = "en-GB";
var ci = new CultureInfo(defaultDateCulture);
ci.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator = "!";
ci.NumberFormat.NumberGroupSeparator = "~";

// Configure the Localization middleware
app.UseRequestLocalization(new RequestLocalizationOptions
{
    DefaultRequestCulture = new RequestCulture(ci),
    SupportedCultures = new List<CultureInfo>
    {
        ci,
    },
    SupportedUICultures = new List<CultureInfo>
    {
        ci,
    }
});

//..other middleware....
```

In the View, I use `N` key word to format common numeric type.

[image]

```
@model decimal

<h1>@Model.ToString("N")</h1>
```

**Result:**

[image]

You can see the format of decimal is what we set in localization.

Refer to this [Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-numeric-format-strings) to check more `Standard numeric format strings`.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. But what I'm looking for is if the view is possible to show the right format without needing to write the .ToString("N") ?
Is there a way I can overwrite the way data is rendered in a view, so that it formats the numbers automatically?

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm afraid this can't be displayed automatically, According to  Docs, You  needs to specify a realistic format for decimal in the View.

Comment: Your comment actually gave me the answer, but yeah I'll mark it no problem.